# How to avoid calling reloadData if no data has changed?

Tags: swift, database, uitableview

I have an app which populates a `UITableView` with information stored in an array. Any time the user opens that particular page, I have a function in the `viewDidLoad()` which, generally, does the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    tableArray.removeAll()
    //query information from a database
    //populate tableArray with this information
    self.table.reloadData()
}
```

What this allows me to do is to query the database for all information relevant to the table at the loading of the page. It works functionally, but I am suspicious that it is not as efficient as it could be.
The current set up calls this function on ***every*** load, regardless if the information being displayed in the table has changed in the database or not. What this means is that often the table will be reloaded with the exact same data. This is a waste of time considering it involves querying the database, appending the array, and then reloading the data to basically display the exact same information that would be displayed if nothing had been done. There is merit to this approach, to some extent, if the information ***has*** changed because the reloading will take this into account. However, even this approach I believe can be improved. If there was a way to identify *which* specific information has changed, I would like to just reload the data for that specific cell. Is this possible? Additionally, is there a way to check if ***any*** information has changed, and then proceed depending on that result?

Comment: How else are you going to populate a table view in a newly displayed view controller if you don't load the data and reload the table view?

Answer (score 0):

Querying information from the database and populating the tableArray are going to be the most expensive part of what you're going to do.  The reloadData() call is practically free compared to those two other things.